# Nuances of JavaScript Prototyping

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, object, prototype

In Chrome when i'm doing this:

```
 var A = function(){};
 A.prototype =  { a:1,b:2 };
 var aInst = new A;
 aInst.a = 11;
 console.log(aInst);
```

I see this in console:

[image]

I didn't see `Object`s with two properties with the same name ("`a`") before, something wrong with my Chrome?

Here: http://jsfiddle.net/4Zws3/1/

Comment: That's a good question, but can you please pick non-infantile variable names?

Comment: There is a difference between instance members and prototype members: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941

Comment: @HMR , i've updated my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4Zws3/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One `a` is an instance property, the other is a value of the prototype object.

I'm actually seeing this in Chrome:

[image]

Comment: i know it , but why chrome sometimes displaying it in a "wrong" way?

Comment: @Cherniv yes, it's a bug.